# Sql stopping returning data with no error

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I'm using mysql and php to show some data, here is my code :

```
<?php

require_once('sqlconnect.php');

$sqlQuery = "SELECT name FROM hiltonsmythe.hs_listing_types LIMIT 120"; 
$result = $unity_connection->query($sqlQuery);

$json1 = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json1[] = $rows;
}   
echo json_encode($json1);

?>
```

This works fine when i navigate to the php file, but if i change the LIMIT to 121 it doesnt return anything even though the table has over 300 fields. When i run the select in SQLWorkbench it works fine.

Anyone know what this could be? i will eventually need to return around 400 i am not sure why it is stopping, there is no error at all on firebug.

edit : i added

> error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

still no results..

[image]

This is the sql connection file :

```
<?php
    class SQLConnection {
        private $mysqli;
        public function __construct ($host, $user, $pass, $name) {
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
            $connectionAttempts = 1;
            while ($this->mysqli == null && $connectionAttempts < 5){
                sleep(1);
                $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
                $connectionAttempts++;
            }

            if($this->mysqli->connect_error){
                die("$this->mysqli->connect_errno: $this->mysqli->connect_error");
            }
        }

        public function __destruct(){
            $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        public function query($sql, $params = null){
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
            return $result;

        }

        public function real_escape_string($string){
            return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($string);
        }

        public function getConnection(){
            return $this->mysqli;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: have you tried with  mysqli_fetch_row?

Comment: not sure what the issue is but try $json1 = mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: what happens if you remove the LIMIT altogether?

Comment: Ive tried fetch row and fetch all, none work- if i remove the LIMIT i get no results, it's as if it cant have more than 120 results lol.

Comment: If it's a memory issue as stated in an answer below, then error reporting would have probably caught that. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also error checking via MySQL http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php since I don't see where you are checking for errors in the query.

Comment: You can extend the timeout with mysql.connect_timeout key in php.ini.

Comment: Don't check for server errors in firebug, check your error log.

Comment: There is no timeout, its only pulling data from 150 rows ,words with less than 10 chars it shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i added errors but got none still

Comment: what about adding an ORDER BY or GROUP BY - ? and did you check for errors in MySQL against the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php ?

Comment: Use LIMIT 0,1000000 and show the output.

Comment: @RaviHirani no output

Comment: *Unable to reproduce*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ill add my sql connection file to the question

Comment: Thanks, but you're already connected so that isn't the problem. I copied your code and used it in a db where I have 1000+ entries and was successful, so something else is breaking this.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  could it be something to do with the database being on a godaddy shared web host? Ill try the same thing in local

Comment: That I couldn't say.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem may be a limit on the script memory. Try to run this code:

```
<?php

require_once('sqlconnect.php');
ini_set("memory_limit","256M"); // add this memory_limit
$sqlQuery = "SELECT name FROM hiltonsmythe.hs_listing_types LIMIT 120"; 
$result = $unity_connection->query($sqlQuery);

$json1 = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json1[] = $rows;
}   
echo json_encode($json1);

?>
```

Comment: Still no return at all, just blank.

Comment: @GazSmith if you create a empty file with a php error (syntax error) does it displays the error?

Comment: @KeyneViana Yeah, i did this in the same file 
$result = $unity_connection->query($sqlQuery);aacqFQDWQD
and i got a php error

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to increase max_allowed_packet in my.ini?  please don't forget to restart MySQL after changing this setting.